# Как правильно вызывать обработчик команды/запроса из обработчика другой команды/запроса при использовании MediatR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cqrs, mediatr

Нужно ли использовать такое:

```
private IMediator _mediator;
protected IMediator Mediator => _mediator ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMediator>();
```

и потом вызывать `Mediator.Send(...)`?

Или надо создавать экземпляр контроллера, в котором есть вызов нужной команды/запроса?
Или вообще другое?

Comment: а зачем вам вызывать mediatr из команды? или вы имели ввиду из обработчика этой команды? тогда проблем не должно быть, просто нужно через конструктор добавить IMediator

Comment: Ну вот если, к примеру, для выполнения команды мне нужно получить элемент по Id, а уже существует такой запрос GetProductByIdQuery, то стоит использовать этот самый запрос или просто заново с помощью Linq и EF вытаскивать из бд? Не понимаю, как правильно поступить, чтобы избегать повторов и использовать то, что нужно

Comment: @ExplodingKitten да, наверное, все-таки правильнее сказать из обработчика. Просто делал по уроку, а там сразу класс команды и в нем же класс обработчика

Comment: Это ASP.NET Core? Добавьте соответствующий тег к вопросу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пусть у Вас есть примерно такой обработчик запроса. Он просто получает данные о продукте из БД

```
public class GetProductByIdQueryHandler: IRequestHandler<GetProductByIdQuery, Product>
{
    private readonly CatalogDbContext _dbContext;

    public GetProductByIdQueryHandler(CatalogDbContext dbContext) => _dbContext = dbContext;

    public Task<Product> Handle(GetProductByIdQuery query, CancellationToken ct) => 
        _dbContext.Products.SingleOrDefaultAsync(product => product.Id == query.Id, ct);
}
```

И есть обработчик команды AddProductToBasketCommand, который, добавляет товар в корзину, а для этого надо получить цену этого товара, логично применить для этого GetProductByIdQueryHandler, это делается так:

```
public class AddProductToBasketCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<AddProductToBasketCommand>
{
    private readonly BasketDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public AddProductToBasketCommandHandler(CatalogDbContext dbContext, IMediator mediator)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    public async Task<Unit> Handle(AddProductToBasketCommand command, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        // Вот здесь зовём обработчика GetProductByIdQuery
        var product = await _mediator.Send(new GetProductByIdQuery {Id = command.ProductId}, ct);

        // Здесь делаем с этим продуктом что-то...
    }
}
```

Вообще, и паттерн медиатор в целом и библиотека MediatR в частности о том, что компоненты вообще не знают друг о друге, то есть есть некий обработчик, который знает, как обработать запрос GetProductByIdQuery, есть другой, который знает, что делать с AddProductToBasketCommand, но друг о друге они не знают, а, если им надо воспользоваться услугами друг друга, то они просто говорят некоему посреднику: «Слушай, а найди там кого-нибудь, кто может обработать вот этот запрос/команду, пусть сделает, что надо и передаст через тебя результат», это позволяет создавать приложения с очень слабой связью между компонентами.

P.S. Контроллеры, о которых Вы упомянули, здесь совсем не при чём, вообще веб-фреймворк, которым пользуетесь надо расценивать, как нечто, что может авторизовать запрос и сериализовать/десериализовать данные, не более и создавать контроллеры руками точно не стоит.

Comment: Благодарю за столь развернутый и понятный ответ! Про контроллер имею в виду то, что есть `ProductController`, в котором есть, к примеру, метод `CreateProduct`, в теле которого есть вызов нужной команды через `Mediator.Send(...)`. Наверное, стоит поискать другие статьи, если это плохой подход